# Arduino class destructor called while object is still in scope

Tags: c++, arduino, destructor, esp8266

I'm working on a small class for the ESP8266 and I need to be able to hold a reference to an object in another instance of the same object. When running the code I've been getting Exceptions. After some debugging it looks like the class destructor is called while the object is still in scope. I've not worked with C++ for a long time but this behavior seems wrong.

There are really two questions.

1. Why is the destructor called when the object is still in scope?
2. Is it possible to hold a reference to the object past the scope of the object without the destructor being called (as in a linked list)?

I've reduced the code to a small program that shows the issue. In the code below the class destructor is called on the 'child' object while it's still in scope. It's actually called twice as I point out in the code.

Here's the output from the code:

```
        Starting
        adding child to root
        Out of scope name=child
        adding child to root2
        Out of scope name=child
        Done, both root and child should still be in scope
```

```
#include "Arduino.h"

class TestObject {
    private:
       char name[20];
       TestObject* child;

    public:
       TestObject(const char* name);
       virtual ~TestObject();
       void setChild(TestObject h) ;
       char *getName();
};

TestObject::TestObject(const char *name) {
    child = (TestObject*)0;
    strcpy(this->name,name);
}

TestObject::~TestObject() {
    Serial.println("Out of scope name="+String(name));
}

char *TestObject::getName() {
    return name;
}

void TestObject::setChild(TestObject h ) {
    child = &h;
    Serial.println("adding "+String(h.name)+" to "+String(name));
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("\nStarting");
  TestObject root = TestObject("root");
  TestObject child = TestObject("child");
  root.setChild(child); // child destructor is called here but it should still be in scope
  delay(1000);
  TestObject root2 = TestObject("root2");
  root2.setChild(child);// child destructor is called a second time here
  Serial.println("Done, both root and child should still be in scope");
  while(true) {
    delay(10000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`TestObject::setChild` takes its parameter by *value*, so that a copy of the `TestObject` is created, used by the function, then destroyed.  This is the source of the destructor that you're seeing.  `setChild` also takes a pointer to this local copy, so that the `child` pointer in the `TestObject` refers to an object that has been destroyed.

The solution is to pass the parameter by *reference*:

```
void TestObject::setChild(TestObject &h)
```

Comment: It would be better to pass a pointer:  it's a common convention that functions should not store references/pointers to objects that were passed by reference.  Having to use `&` operator alerts the call site that they need to be thinking about the lifetime of the object they're passing.

Answer (score 0):

In void setChild(TestObject h) ; you set the member's child pointer to the address of a temporary (the parameter). You likely want to pass a reference void setChild(TestObject & h) ; but even then the child pointer will do nothing to extend the lifeltime of an object.

Comment: Any thought on how one might manage the object life cycle so that it could be stored in a list that live past the scope of the current block?